# SourceForge multiDatesPicker control not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to use the above subject control, but it is functioning just like a datepicker control.

**How can I use the control to select multiple dates?**

Here is the HTML:

```
    <link href="../Content/assets/css/jquery-ui.structure.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/prettify.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="dteCalendarSetup" />
```

Here is the JS:

```
$(function ()
    {
        $('#dteCalendarSetup').multiDatesPicker();
    });
```

Here is a picture of how the calendar should look:
[image]

Here is a picture of the calendar I'm getting:
[image]

Comment: What jQuery-UI theme are you using?

Comment: I don't care about the theme.... I just want the functionality to work where I can select multiple days.

Comment: You may need to pass some options to the control (see demo [here](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/#maxPicks-demo)) to enable multi-picking.

Comment: Not according to the Simplest usage demo at the same link. You can click on multiple dates.